# HTML Form doesn't send data to the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I know there are questions similar to this but their answers doesn't solve my problem.

My php is running without errors (at least not from the navigator), it even returns me the custom url I set at the end of my script `?register=success` but it doesn't send the data to my database(local).

I really don't know what section of my code I should let here because, as I said at the begining, there are not errors from php in the navigator, so I just put all my main php (register.php).

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST["submit"])){        
    include_once "dbh_inc.php";        
    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["first"]);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["last"]);
    $nickname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["nickname"]);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["password"]);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]);

    //Birthdate
    $birthDay = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["birth-day"]);
    $birthMonth = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["birth-month"]);
    $birthAge = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["birth-age"]);
    $birthDate = $birthDay."-".$birthMonth."-".$birthAge;


    $speciality = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["speciality"]);
    $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["gender"]);

    //Error handlers
    //Check for empty fields

    if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($last) || empty($last) || empty($last)) {
      header("Location: ../register.php?register=empty");
      exit();
    }else{
      //Check if input characters are valid
      if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last)){
        header("Location: ../register.php?register=invalid");
        exit();
      }else{
        //Check if email is valid
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          header("Location: ../register.php?register=email");
          exit();
        }else{
          //Check if birthdate is valid
          if (!checkdate ($birthMonth , $birthDay, $birthAge)) {
            header("Location: ../register.php?register=date");
            exit();
          }else{
            //Check if user exists
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_nickname='$nickname'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            //Entering to the database to check if username exists
            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
              header("Location: ../register.php?register=usertaked");
              exit();
            }else{
              //Hashing the password
              $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
              //Insert user registration data into the database                  
              $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_first, user_last, user_nickname, user_password, user_email, user_birth_date, user_speciality, user_gender) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$nickname', '$password', '$email', '$birthDate', '$speciality', '$gender')";
              mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
              header("Location: ../register.php?register=success");
              exit();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }else{
    header("Location: ../register.php");
    exit();
  }
```

And this is the php where I do the connection with the database (dbh_inc.php):

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";//because there's running a local server
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "login_system";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName) or die ("Conexion fallida");
```

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly. Use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get a detailed error message from the database.

Comment: You can probably have the die function also include the error message instead of just a static string.

Comment: Are you trying to insert this into a column expecting a date value? `$birthDate = $birthDay."-".$birthMonth."-".$birthAge;` Also this amused me so much, you really dont want last empty do you? `if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($last) || empty($last) || empty($last))`

Comment: @miknik oh i don't realize that, now I regret for post that. And yes, I was trying to find a way to insert a formated date but I don't know much about php, that is the result of view some tutorials on YT.